# Autotune Ventrillo

Tags: windows, audio, processing, autotune

How do I autotune my voice before it gets sent over ventrillo (with free software only)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) to the rescue (again).  JACK is a software patch bay for sound signals; it can route sound inputs & outputs between programs and through processing plugins before finally sending it to whereever the signal needs to go (a soundcard output, or a program like Ventrillo).

You can find free [autotune and pitch-shifting VST](http://www.wavosaur.com/vst/pitchshift-autotune-plugins.php) and [LADSPA](http://web.mit.edu/tbaran/www/autotalent.html) plugins.  JACK lets you run the mic input through the plugins before passing it to Ventrillo.